# Is it possible to store extra data in session store on DB ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, session-state, asp.net-core-3.1, sql-session-state

Is there a way to store extra data in the SessionStorage tables generated by the SQL Server session provider in an ASP.NET Core 3 MVC Web application?

For example in the ASPStateTempSessions table, add the username, IP address and browser from which the user is entering the web application.

For security reasons, we need to prevent users from having multiple sessions, and due to design rules of the company we cannot send the data to a separate database or table

Comment: Is it ASP.NET application, or ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: It is an ASP.NET Core 3 application